# Slug for dynamic routing in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, express, next.js

I am new to Nextjs and I am getting confused with the dynamic links and routing. Do we have to use Slug in order to achieve this?

I am able to get a link but when I try to click on the **title** link it does not take me to a page where I can view the title and body of that particular post. I have uploaded the code in the above link but have not understood the proper way to do so.

Comment: you are not setting the value of the title in the state. <Link href={`/post?title=${this.state.post.title}`} ><a>  might solve your issue

Comment: I get this error: Property 'post' does not exist on type '{ title: string; body: string; posts: any[]; }'. Did you mean 'posts'?ts(2551)

When I change it to posts instead of post then I get error: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'any[]'. @visizky

Comment: try title=${post.title}

Comment: do you have a pages/post.tsx file?

Comment: no, but after I create that, what should I add within it? @visizky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208913/discussion-between-rebel-and-visizky).